# Please check pictures below and guide

Tags: javascript, html, css

As a beginner i need to know what these 2 techniques are called (*i annotated them in the images*) and where do i can find them.

The images are screenshots from Twitter.

The first one would be the menu that flys-out end the second one is a popup, where do i find the JavaScript for those techiques.

I want to add them for my project

[image: on twitter clicking on setting it shows drawer or drop down like]

[image: twitter click on msg it shows a compose msg page]

Comment: The first is a "menu". The second is an "awful, pink modal". Is that really all you need to know?

Comment: You can and should down vote no problem for me but at least told me what i asked

Comment: i said how both these two things can be made and trying to find their particular to technique to make that

Comment: @Maria He actually answered what you asked.. though maybe one can add 'dropdown' in front of 'menu' and 'popup box' behind 'pink modal'. Go ahead and google 'dropdown menu' to start with.

Comment: @Marcel Thankx :) popup box i needed to know  ....and i know its dropdown menu i made that before but still in twitter it is different more silk anyways thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the Twitter site, maybe you should take a look @ [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), thats the technology that is used in your screenshots.

For the flyout menu, [dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) are used

For the popup, [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) is used

Comment: Big Thankx for both links i think i can work with modals link THankx Again treating me as a student :)

Comment: FOr those who wants to make Modal popup windows with help of Html5 and css3 it is worth reading Article :) http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/